# Oracle SQL developer- Create Table from Table and View

Tags: oracle

I have one table and view where one column is common which is the primary key of the table. Now if I want to join the table and view only with specific columns, should I create view or table in that case? Also I want to import the joined result to Tableau.

Comment: What if I want to join two views to create a new table? Which join is appropriate to use?

Answer (score 0):

Well If you want just join table and view in single query you may write it, or you may create view for it, if you want. For example:

```
  create table tmp_table_a (id, first_col, second_col, third_col) as
  select level, lpad('a',level,'b'), lpad('c',level,'d'), lpad('e',level,'f') 
  from dual connect by level < 101;

  create view v_tmp_a as 
  select id, substr(first_col,1,10) as first_sub_col from tmp_table_a;
```

simple query:

```
 select second_col, third_col, first_sub_col 
 from tmp_table_a t1, v_tmp_a v1
 where t1.id = v1.id;
```

or create view:

```
 create view v_join_a as 
 select second_col, third_col, first_sub_col 
 from tmp_table_a t1, v_tmp_a v1
 where t1.id = v1.id; 

 select * from v_join_a;
```

Comment: What if I want to join two views to create a new table? Which join is appropriate to use?

Comment: It depends of what join you need. You may don't care of objects and think about view as about table